# ElasticSearch сортировка

Tags: сортировка, elasticsearch

На клиенте есть специальная сортировка реализовання через интерфейс Comparator.
Со своей логикой и private методами.

Можно ли сделать, чтоб сортировка происходила не на уровне клиента, а на уровне ЕlasticSearch?

Comment: так?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html

Answer (score 1):

Да можно.

Пример:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search' -d '{
   "query" : {
    ...
   },
   "sort" : [
      {"price" : {"order" : "asc", "mode" : "avg"}}
   ]
}'
```

Подробнее можете узнать [тут](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html).

Comment: Не совсем то, приходит поле номер документа, оно парсится на состовляющие (первая и вторая часть) затем в зависимости от условий в методе comapre идет анализ

Comment: Вы хотите какую то логику привязать к эластику?

Comment: Да именно так... Чтоб сортировка выполнялось с парсингом и анализом на уровне сервера

Comment: В таком случае вам необходимо написать индексы и возможно кастомный анализатор для эластика. Если вам не хватит возможностей кастомного анализатора, то вы можете прибегнуть к написанию процедур для бд.

Comment: Я наисал плагин, получаю данные, паршу, все OK. А как сравнивать с другими строчками наподобии comparator или по другому?

Comment: Сравнение делайте теле запроса.